# What does it mean "Fiscal inactivity" in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've listened to a phrase at the short video lecture in Reading university in the UK which states:

> "**Fiscal inactivity**, sedentary behaviour, and poor eating choices
>   can all contribute to obesity."

Then I've checked in the dictionary and I found 1 definition: 
"Fiscal- relating to government revenue, especially taxes.". I can't get the relationship between the government revenue and obesity.

n.b. It is not physical activity but Fiscal activity. [see here](https://ugc.futurelearn.com/uploads/files/a3/88/a3883b0e-40b4-4128-a887-7caafc7ccc6f/Obesity.pdf) (in the beginning of the 6th phrase).
[image]

Comment: It sounds like a pretty daft attempt to euphemistically refer to *not having a job, being unemployed, earning no wages* (equated by some of the popular press with *lazing around at home all day, doing nothing except eat crisps and watch daytime TV*).

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers. The distinction between "fiscal" and "financial" isn't nearly as clear as your dictionary implies, and many people use them interchangeably.

Comment: You sure it's not "**physical** inactivity"?

Comment: @TRomano: I suppose that's feasible if it was dictated using speech-to-text - but it's hardly the kind of *spelling mistake* you'd expect from someone associated with a university, however loosely. At the end of the day though, it's not exactly "quality" text, and any significance to the unusual phrasing isn't really relevant to "learning English".

Comment: @Colin Fine: If I were being charitable, I'd allow that the writer *might* have wished to obliquely refer to *listlessness, low self-esteem, depression* seen as both consequences of being unemployed, and causes of obesity. But I don't think I'm feeling very charitable today! :)

Comment: @TRomano- Yes, I am sure, as I edited and mentioned now in the post.

Comment: I would bet ten bags of potato chips that the author meant to write *physical inactivity*.

Comment: It could be the original meaning but when I saw it written in the transcription, then as a non-native English speaker I couldn't let myself to judge and I had to bring in front of those who know the language well and can make right decision.

Comment: I missed that this was a transcription of a lecture. I agree that a mistranscription of _physical_ is by far the most likely answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the person who made the transcript of the video made a mistake. It would be easy to mishear "physical" as "fiscal" if you're being paid a pittance to transcribe thousands of words every day. But failure to pay your taxes doesn't make you fat; sitting on your bum all day does.